# Avoid NULL columns using DEFAULT Empty String

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

How can I create a column with the default value being an empty string?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can read up on the subject [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174123(SQL.100).aspx)

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Test (ID INTEGER, EmptyString VARCHAR(32) DEFAULT '')

INSERT INTO dbo.Test (ID) VALUES (1)
INSERT INTO dbo.Test (ID) VALUES (2)

SELECT * FROM dbo.Test

DROP TABLE dbo.Test
```

Comment: What database is this? In Oracle, if you set a VARCHAR to '', it becomes NULL.

Comment: @Brian Hooper, OP said *using MS SQL 2008*. Nevertheless, good to know Oracle works differently, thanks.

Comment: Ah. Either some tags have appeared recently or I need new glasses. Sorry, chaps.

Comment: @Brian, don't worry, your eyes are fine. I changed the tags after your comment and removed the *using MS SQL 2008* from the question.

Answer (score 10):

In SQL server you can set "Column properties > Default value or binding" section to `('')`. NOTE: It includes single quotation and parenthesis

Answer (score 9):

Something like:

`CREATE TABLE foobar (string_column VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '')`